# Jmeter thread group duration

Tags: java, jmeter, traffic

I have this situation:

- Thread Group (n_threads=X,duration Y sec)

  - Loop

    - Java Sampler

When the test duration ends, Jmeter does not stop the threads that were making requests and therefore the test does not terminate. How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen in the case when response time of your "Java Sampler" is higher than your test duration. I would recommend introducing reasonable timeout into your Java code so the samplers would fail/exit instead of waiting forever for the response. If you have no idea what's going on there - take a [thread dump](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-dump) and see where your thread(s) stuck

As the workaround, the only way to "terminate" the test I can think of would be:

1. Adding another Thread Group with 1 thread
2. Adding [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) with the following code:

   ```
   sleep(5000) // wait for 5 seconds, amend accordingly to your desired test duration
   log.info('Exceeded test duration')
   System.exit(1)   // the process will exit with non-zero exit code (error), change it to 0 if needed
   ```

   See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for more information on Groovy scripting concept in JMeter

Also be aware that this code will terminate the whole JVM so it will probably make sense to add [`jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) line to *user.properties* as forcibly terminating the whole JVM might lead to some results loss.

Comment: Hi Dimitri, this work also if I check the option "run thread group consecutively" ?